# Laravel pass parameters from controller to Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new in laravel and I am trying to pass parameters from a function in controller to a function in model. I have done this :

My controller

```
class DashBoardController extends BaseController {
    public function yesterdayOrderData(){
        $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today -1 days'));
        $to = str_replace("00:00:00", "23:59:59", $from);
        $odata = Invoice::yesterdaysorderdetails($from, $to);
    }

}
```

My Model :

```
class Invoice extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'Inf_Invoice';
    public function scopeyesterdaysorderdetails($from, $to){
        echo $from."--".$to;
    }
}
```

I am getting error message `"Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder could not be converted to string"`

How can I pass parameters from my controller to model ??

Comment: You can use the `dd()` function in Laravel to Dump and Die which may help debug your error. e.g. `dd($from)`

Comment: The error says that `Eloquent\Builder` instance can't be converted to string. And this happens because it is unshifted as 1st parameter to every scope call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope requires `query` instance to be 1st param (it's automatically passed to the function):

```
// you don't need to use camelCase, but it's soooo hard to read this otherwise..
public function scopeYesterdaysOrderDetails($query, $from, $to){
     $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to]);
}


// usage:
$odata = Invoice::yesterdaysOrderDetails($from, $to)->get();
```

Just a note about the method name - it should follow one rule - first letter after the `scope` part **should be uppercase**.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your function name from `scopeyesterdaysorderdetails` to `yesterdaysorderdetails`. It seems [scopes are special functions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) and they take only one parameter `$query` which is probably Eloquent Builder and that's why you get this error.

And in your situation you just want to display 2 dates separated with `--` so you don't need scope functions for that, just normal function that cannot begin with `scope` I think

Comment: if i use `scopeyesterdaysorderdetails($from, $to)` I get an error undefined method. I dont know exactly but scope is used for writing multiple qeries and from controller we can call function without having to write scope. Not sure.. I am learning laravel

Comment: @Illusion I haven't used scope function either. I've edited my answer

Comment: Ok.. I will give that a try.. Post you back in a moment.

Comment: I tried without scope and I am getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::getyesterdaysorderdetails()`

Comment: @Illusion Have you changed function name both in Model and controller to `getyesterdaysorderdetails` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek scopes are exactly for such situations. They do not accept **only** query parameter, but 1st parameter is always the query, that scope should be applied on. You just need to take that into consideration in the scope function declaration.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I'm still learning, but I thought OP just want to display `echo $from."--".$to;` without any queries. It seems I misunderstood what OP wants to achieve

Comment: Yeah, I understand. About the OP code - I suppose this was just for learning purposes, and in fact it won't be just `echo` call.